# How to generate string variable with crlf at ttl language

Tags: printf, teraterm

I'm trying to make string that contain crlf inside it at ttl language. For example, somthing such as:

```
MY_STRING = "hello\nworld"
send  MY_STRING
```

should result as

```
hello
world
```

I know I can get the same with:

```
send "hello" #13#10 "world"
```

but I need it as string because I want to 'send' this string to another 'function', for example:

```
MY_STRING = "hello\nworld"
include "printMyString.ttl"
```

I tried something like:

```
sprintf2 MY_STRING "%s\n%s" "hello" "world"
sprintf2 MY_STRING "%s%d%d%s" "hello" 13 10 "world"
sprintf2 MY_STRING "%s%d%d%s" "hello" #13 #10 "world"
```

but it didn't worked, is there is a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some way, maybe there is better:

```
code2str CRLF $0d0a
sprintf2 MY_STRING "%s%s%s" "hello" CRLF "world"
send  MY_STRING
```

EDIT
It comes out that my first approach was good, just didn't understand that #13 is string:

```
sprintf2 MY_STRING "%s%s%s%s" "hello" #13 #10 "world"
send  MY_STRING
```